# Chip based logic, NOR by sn74hc02n analog

Tags: digital-logic, diodes, logic-gates, breadboard

I think I'm not understand something obvious when trying to implement the complex logic(half-adder) by NORs. Possible to simplify my question, why in this position the diod is emitting:[image: first working example]

In this state the Diode just connected to + and - ...

But when I trying to connect the diode to digital output of the chip it's not working:
[image: first non-working example]

[image: second non-working example]
Here connected through VCC, and the diode connected to the NOR output.

In description written - it is analog, but not only in logic misunderstanding.
Even when I'm connecting the diode just near to chip(without VCC to chip) it is also not emit.
I also tried to connect through VCC - and with my understanding it must works, but not. What I don't understand?

Comment: That chip is not a SN74HC02, and from what I've found, KP1554 is not compatible with HC. Please link to its datasheet. Also, provide the schematic of your circuit.

Comment: @CL. https://eandc.ru/pdf/mikroskhema/kr1554le1.pdf but it is in russian

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I trying to connect the diode to digital output of the chip it's not working

1. You've mixed up the pinout of the chip, and you're not connecting the supply voltage to pins 14 (+) and 7 (-). The way you've connected it, the chip's input protection diodes are active, and the chip shorts the VCC and GND, just as if you've connected a diode from VCC to GND.
2. All CMOS logic families require that *all* inputs are connected to a valid logic level. You've left all inputs disconnected (!).
3. A LED requires a series resistor. The LED is either getting hot, or the power supply is limiting current. Connect a 1kΩ resistor in series with the LED.

The following corrections are needed:

1. Connect (+) to pin 14, (-) to pin 7.
2. Connect all input pins - 2,3,5,6,8,9,11,12 to either (+) or (-). The outputs are on pins 1,4,10,13.
3. Add a series resistor in series with the LED.

Below is the pinout of 74xx02, КР1554ЛЕ1, KR1554LE1 (from [TI 74AC02 datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/gpn/CD74AC02)). Inputs are denoted A and B. Outputs are Y. The digit signified which of the four gates in the chip the pins belong to.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving the chip a power supply.

In the second picture you are shorting out the LED with a wire.

In the third picture, the LED is on chip pin, but again you are feeding same voltage node to both chip pins.